# Automatically generate combobox when inserting a number in another combobox

Tags: html, asp.net, ajax

I want to enter a combobox a number and that automatically I paint the amount of combobox in the web page, can someone help me with some tutorial?

[image: combo]

In the combobox if I insert 5 I want it to be generated in another div automatically 5 combobox in which I will receive an integer. And if I insert 0 do not want anything to be generated, an example is on the following page 
http: //www.pricetravel .com.mx /

In the hotels section if you enter a number greater than zero, the fields are automatically generated

Comment: "I want to enter a combobox a number" This is very unclear.  Can you be more specific?

Comment: Post what you've tried so far.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have written a Jquery code to fulfil your requirement.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#cbo-select").change(selectedElementChanged);

});

function selectedElementChanged() {

  var selectedValue = $("#cbo-select").val();
  if (parseInt(selectedValue)) {
    $("#area").empty();
    for (var i = 0; i < selectedValue; i++) {
      $("#area").append('<select><option>test</option></select></br>');
    }
  }

}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <script data-require="jquery@3.0.0" data-semver="3.0.0" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0/jquery.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

  <select id="cbo-select">
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
    <option value="4">4</option>
    <option value="5">5</option>
  </select>

  <div id="area">

  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: if I want that the new combobox will create horizontally?

Comment: just remove the </br> from appending line.
$("#area").append('<select><option>test</option></select>');

Comment: When I choose zero always appear one select, How can i do to delete select when i choose zero?

Comment: move   $("#area").empty(); before if condition.

Comment: and i have another question If I select 4 and I generate 4 selected and fill them with a value but then I better I want 8 I want to preserve the value of the old 4 and add the 4 missing

Comment: Sorry , I didn't get you? can you explain me more?